# MySQL trigger/check on INSERT based on multiple factors (location, date and time)

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have a shift schedule planner for various warehouses. I'm trying to add multiple checks at DB level. If I'm using a composite key (by removing ***shift_id***) to match staff, location,date time it's works but it doesn't solve the shift overlapping problem (e.g if I insert exact same data as ***shift_id 1*** but instead of 09:00 start time is 09:01 will accept as valid shift).

[image: Schema]

In below example, the INSERT should fail for ***shift_id 2*** because, the shift time is overlapped for same ***staff_id 1*** on same date The next available shift for same staff (on same date and same location or a different one) should be available after 13:00. For ***shift_id 3*** should be another fail because ***staff_id 1*** is already scheduled for exact same date and same hours to another location (***location_id 1***). However, ***shift_id 4 *** should be accepted because is not overlapping the shift start/end for same staff id.

[image: Conditions]

I was trying to add table constraint to compare shift_start and shift_end but unsuccessfully:

```
 ADD CONSTRAINT NoDoubleShifts CHECK(
    NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM Shift S1, Shift S2
            WHERE s1.shift_date + s1.shift_start < s2.shift_date + s2shift_start
            AND s1.shift_date + s1.shift_end > s2.shift_Date + s2shift_start)
```

MySQL throws errors (I'm guessing that the constraint is not well formatted "*A statement was found, but no delimiter between it near CHECK"*).

The second trying solution was to add a trigger BEFORE INSERT in different combinations but didn't work either. Is calculating the time but is preventing me to add any other staff (with different id) during that time slot.

```
begin
  if exists (select * from shift
             where shift_start <= new.shift_end
             and shift_end >= new.shift_start ) then
    signal sqlstate '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Shifts are overlapping';
  end if;
end;
```

Any help and constructive comments or anyone to point me in right direction will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You should be able to add `and staff_id=NEW.staff_id` to your exists subquery in the trigger to solve the problem.

Comment: omg... so simple thing. I'm quite sure I tried yesterday but didn't work.. probably I typed something wrong. Thank you very much for opening my eyes... well is 8:20 am now so probably with a fresh view typed correctly. Thank you again Nick..

Comment: No worries. Nicely written question btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Nick suggested in his comment the solution was very simple. Therefore the final trigger would look like :

```
begin
  if exists (select * from shift
             where shift_start <= new.shift_end
             and shift_end >= new.shift_start
             and staff_id = new.staff_id) then
    signal sqlstate '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Shifts are overlapping';
  end if;
end
```

Thanks again to Nick....

Comment: I didn't realise they made you wait so long.